# How to insert row below the clicked row in angular 2

Tags: angular

I have a code shown below:

```
<tr *ngFor = "let data of values; let i = index">
  <td>
     <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" (change) = "insertRow(i)">
     </label>
     <a (click) = "getTerms(data.id)">{{data.id}}</a>
  </td>
  <td>{{data.desc}}</td>
</tr>
```

And I have a requirement where I need to insert a row below the row for which checkbox is clicked. I have tried to find out index and append below index but was not successful. Please let me know how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing index as a params of your `getTerms()`, you can pass the [$event](https://angular.io/guide/user-input#get-user-input-from-the-event-object) like this:

```
<a (click) = "getTerms($event)">{{data.id}}</a>
```

Then in your component you can do this:

```
getTerms(e) {
    console.log(e.target);
    // supposed you are using jQuery
    // update
    $('<tr>New row</tr>').insertAfter($(e.target).closest('tr'));
}
```

You got the current target, then find the `tr` parent of the clicked target.

Comment: Thanks! Below line of code works `$('<tr></tr>').insertAfter($(event.target).parent().parent());`. I need to insert new row(tr).

Comment: Update my answer